# NSPathControl set path

Tags: objective-c, path, nspathcontrol

I am looking for a way to set the path of an NSPathControl to be "~/Desktop".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[_pathControlOutlet setURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [@"~/Desktop"stringByExpandingTildeInPath] ]];


NSURL *pathURL = [_pathControlOutlet URL];
NSLog(@"%@",[[_pathControlOutlet URL]path]);

NSString *pathSegmentClicked = [[_pathControlOutlet clickedPathComponentCell]title];

NSLog(@"%@",pathSegmentClicked);
NSLog(@"%@",pathURL);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.Now I am wondering, How do I get the a string of the selected path.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[@"~/Desktop stringByExpandingTildeInPath]];
[pathControl setURL:pathURL];
```